# #linkedinapi: what documents are required for me to apply for linkedin developer app

Tags: linkedin-api

My purpose in writing to you is to seek clarification and guidance on utilizing the LinkedIn API for a project I am currently undertaking. I understand the significance of adhering to the correct procedures and requirements for accessing this valuable resource, and I appreciate your assistance in this matter.

Firstly, I would like to inquire about the current pricing structure for the LinkedIn API. It is important for me to ascertain whether there are any associated costs involved in accessing its various endpoints. Could you kindly provide detailed quotation regarding any fees or subscription plans, if applicable?

Secondly, I am keen to understand the steps involved in getting started with the LinkedIn API, particularly in accessing its different endpoints for integration with my application. Any information or documentation that outlines the prerequisites and procedures for API access would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, I would like to inquire about the process of applying for a LinkedIn developer's App. What specific criteria and documentation are required from me to initiate this application? It would be immensely helpful if you could furnish me with a comprehensive document detailing all the prerequisites and steps necessary for creating an application within my developer's account.

Your expertise and insights on these matters would be invaluable as I embark on this project. I am committed to ensuring full compliance with LinkedIn's policies and guidelines and look forward to your guidance in achieving this objective.

Here attached is SRS document for my project.

Thank you for your time and attention to this inquiry. Your prompt response would be greatly appreciated, and I am open to any further information or guidance you may wish to provide.

Warm regards,

I created an application under linkedin developer's account. I got confused on what permisions to use to pull data for insights and sentiments analysis. I am looking forward to use endpoints like mentions and mentioned comments, extracting posts and their comments and likes as well as impressions.